# IIS 7.5 IP Address Restrictions Not Working

Tags: sharepoint, iis-7, web-hosting

I am attempting to lock down access to a Sharepoint 3 site via the IIS 7 IP Address and Domain Restrictions options. We currently have this setup on numerous Sharepoint 2 site running through IIS 6.

The issue is that after editing the sites Restrictions they do not appear to be taking effect.

I have Edited Feature Settings to Deny Access for unspecified clients and then added a specific allow IP entry. So far this appears to be all good.

I have then attemped to connect from an unspecified IP and I can still connect?! I have then tried to explicitly deny access from an IP and yet again I still can connect on this IP. I am really unsure why this is happening as upon checking the applicationhost.config file I can see the IPSecurity setting has been amended as below

```
</authentication>
                <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
                    <add ipAddress="IP Address*" allowed="true" />
                </ipSecurity>
```

The app pool has been recycled, stopped to see if this helps and I have even stopped/started the site itself. I do not understand why this is not working as under IIS 6 I have never had this problem.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question I found out the cause from my Network team.

It appears that is was due to the setup of our Stingray Load-balancers. They were set to proxy the public IP via their own IP therefore bypassing the IP Restriction settings in IIS as they were using the default gateway.

A tad annoying but at least I know why.